# Implementing a string array property of an Interface type

Tags: c#

So in my interface I have written this:

```
public interface IFileExport
{
    string[] FileHeaders { get; set; }
}
```

And in my class something like this:

```
public class AdditionsFileExport: IFileExport
{
    public string[] FileHeaders {
        get
        {
            return new string["wwwe", "sdd", "e3rs"];
        }
        set { FileHeaders = value; } }
}
```

But I get two errors:

1. Cannot implicitly convert type string to int. (On the GET
       section)
2. Function is recursive on all path. (On the SET section)

What are the wrong things I have done and what is the correct way?

Comment: The part in the `[` `]` should be an integer to specify size, or left empty and values provided (in `{` `}`).

Comment: Since your `get` only returns certain values, you don't (apparently) need a `set` at all. Otherwise you need to change both to use a backing variable.

Comment: Dennis answer is correct. By the way you should not expose arrays publically. If you have enabled code analysis then you will get warnings,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your declaration or array is syntactically incorrect.

```
public class AdditionsFileExport: IFileExport
{        
    // "wwwe", "sdd", "e3rs" will be default values
    private string[] fileHeaders = new[] { "wwwe", "sdd", "e3rs" };
    public string[] FileHeaders 
    {
        get { return fileHeaders; }
        set { fileHeaders = value; } 
    }
}
```

If you need readonly property, remove setter and declare `fileHeaders` with `readonly` keyword.

Note, that this:

```
public class AdditionsFileExport: IFileExport
{        
    public string[] FileHeaders 
    {
        get { return new[] { "wwwe", "sdd", "e3rs" }; }
    }
}
```

isn't a way to go, because every time you call `FileHeaders`, you create new instance of array. Thus, this assertion will fail:

```
var foo = new AdditionsFileExport();
Debug.Assert(foo.FileHeaders == foo.FileHeaders);
```

Also note, that array isn't a good return type in general, because you can't change property implementation, e.g., this way:

```
public class AdditionsFileExport: IFileExport
{        
    private readonly fileHeaders = new List<string>
    {
        "wwwe", "sdd", "e3rs"
    };

    public string[] FileHeaders 
    {
        // won't compile, because List<> isn't array
        get { return fileHeaders; }
    }
}
```

`IEnumerable<string>` would be a better choise here.

Comment: Well if he declare fileHeaders readonly, then set will give error,

Comment: @FaisalHafeez: "If you need readonly property". Otherwise backing field must not be readonly.